# Filter to Month-Day Interval

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a data frame with daily observations across years. I would like to filter to a range, such as "March 10 to May 12" every year. Perhaps it's my poor googling skills, but I couldn't find some sort of month-day construction.

Here's a sample df:

```
set.seed(123)

dates <- seq.Date(from=as.Date("1970-01-01"), to=as.Date("2007-08-31"), by="days")

sample.df <- data.frame(date=dates, 
                        data=rnorm(length(dates)))
```

Another addition to complicate is to keep a range that crosses over years, such as "December 10 to February 2." It can be assumed all needed dates are contained within the dataframe, but might need to make some NA such as when the dataframe goes to 2007, so we cannot do December 10, 2007 to February 2, 2008.

Comment: You have two questions here. Best to separate them into different posts. In the first case, you don't care about year? In the second case, year is critical?

Comment: @ChiPak I want to keep a range every year either way, just in one case the range may go over into another year. The first case is to keep: "March 10, 1970 to May 12, 1970", "March 10, 1971 to May 12, 1971"... In the second, it is keep "December 10, 1970 to February 2, 1971", "December 10, 1971 to February 2, 1972",...  I hope those two cases are similar enough.

Answer (score 4):

This works for any number of years and for arbitrarily complex logical conditions. No packages are used.

```
monthday <- format(sample.df$date, "%m%d")

sample.df[ monthday >= "0310" & monthday <= "0512", ]   # mar 10 - may 12

sample.df[ monthday <= "0202" | monthday >= "1210", ]   # dec 10 - feb 02

sample.df[ monthday <= "0202" | 
           (monthday >= "0310" & monthday <= "0512") | 
           monthday >= "1210", ]   # both
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dplyr` and `lubridate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

sample.df %>% filter(between(date, ymd("2006-03-10"), ymd("2006-05-12")))

sample.df %>% filter(between(date, ymd("2006-10-11"), ymd("2007-02-01")))
```

Ignoring year:

```
sample.df %>% 
   mutate(dummy = (month(date)*100) + day(date)) %>% 
   filter(between(dummy,310,512)) %>% 
   select(-dummy)
```

Comment: Thanks, this only works for one year and becomes kind of tedious for many years though.